# "Unexpected end of file" error in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

I am writing a calendar script that is supposed to accept

- any month in format `mm` or `mmm`, or
- only the year as `yyyy`, or
- both month and year.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test s# -eq 0 
then
    echo "Invalid Arguments"
else
    if test s# -eq 2
    then
        if $1 -gt 1999 -o $2 -gt 12
        then
            echo "invalid Year or month"
        else
            cal $1 $2
            if test s# -eq 1 
            then
                if test $1 -gt 12 
                then
                    cal $1
                else
                    case $1 in 
                        01) m = jan;;
                        02) m = feb;;
                        03) m = mar;;
                        04) m = apr;;
                        05) m = may;;
                        06) m = jun;;
                        07) m = jul;;
                        08) m = aug;;
                        09) m = sep;;
                        10) m = oct;;
                        11) m = nov;;
                        12) m = dec;;
                    esac
                    echo " Calender for $1 Month : "
                    cal $m
                fi
            fi
```

I am getting this error:

> line 38: syntax error: unexpected end of file

How can I fix this?

Comment: There needs to be a matching `fi` for every `if`.

Comment: I have indented your code. The problem should be quite obvious now.

Comment: In the future, I recommend using https://www.shellcheck.net/ before posting questions like this one. It catches a lot of common mistakes.

Comment: All of those `s#` should probably be `$#`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two `fi` in the end of the file.
But, still giving errors here, can you be more explicit on what you're doing, or give the full code ?